# Does exuberant ctags support c++11?

Tags: c++11, vim, enums, exuberant-ctags

I like having my syntax highligthed in vim through the TagHighlight plugin, which uses exuberant ctags to generate a tags file that vim uses for syntax.

Until recently, I was just using regular enum types such as

`enum count {ONE, TWO, THREE};`

which was getting tagged correctly. My group recently decided to support c++11, and I tried

`enum class count {ONE, TWO, THREE};`

The enum "count" is now tagged as a class instead of enum, "ONE" and "TWO" are marked as class members and "THREE" is not tagged at all.

I tried to use 
`--regex-c++=/^[ \t]*(enum)[ \t]+(class)[ \t]+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/\3/e,enum/` as a regular expression, but was unsuccessful. It seems the enum class should be a standard type to generate ctags from, but haven't found anyone complaining about it. Am I stupidly overlooking something simple?

`ctags-exuberant --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Sep 29 2014, 16:06:25
  Addresses: <dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net>, http://ctags.sourceforge.net
  Optional compiled features: +wildcards, +regex`

An alternative approach to custom syntax highlighting in vim would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a more up to date version of exuberant ctags called universal ctags available [here](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags). It has support for C++11 along with many more languages compared to exuberant ctags (the full list is [here](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags/tree/master/parsers)). If you're on mac you can install with homebrew using

```
brew tap universal-ctags/universal-ctags
brew install --HEAD universal-ctags
```

Universal ctags is just a fork of exuberant ctags and should be usable as a complete replacement for it.

Comment: For Arch Linux users: I just found that the [ctags-fishman-git](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ctags-fishman-git/) AUR package  *is* actually `universal-ctags` :)